# How does throw declare throughs 'startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()' in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, guard

I'd import data through the current file selector. I'm looking at the development document and following it, and there's one problem.  I'm about to get an error when I'm not in the condition statement of the guard, but '`throw`' is not available. How can you solve this problem?

```
func startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() -> Bool
```

**Usage**

```swift
    func presentDocument(at documentURL: URL) {


        // Start accessing a security-scoped resource.
        guard documentURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
            throw IXError.fileAcessFailed // Error is not handled because the enclosing function is not declared 'throws'
            return
        }
```

> Error is not handled because the enclosing function is not declared
>   'throws'

I tried `guard let` but failed it.

```swift
        guard let Acess = documentURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { //Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'
            throw IXError.fileAcessFailed // Error is not handled because the enclosing function is not declared 'throws'
            return
        }
```

**IXError**

```
public enum IXError: Error {
    ...
}
```

********************************Edit start ********************************************

I added `throws` according to the answer, but an error occurred in the function that used it.

```swift
    func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didPickDocumentURLs documentURLs: [URL]) {
        guard let sourceURL = documentURLs.first else { return }
        presentDocument(at: sourceURL) // Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
    }
...
    func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didImportDocumentAt sourceURL: URL, toDestinationURL destinationURL: URL) {
        presentDocument(at: destinationURL) // Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
    }
...
    func presentDocument(at documentURL: URL) throws {

        guard documentURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
            throw IXError.fileAcessFailed
            return
        }
```

> Error is Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error
>   is not handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error is not handled because the enclosing function is not declared 'throws'

this refers to your `presentDocument` function. Declare it like so:

```
func presentDocument(at documentURL: URL) throws {
...
}
```

Comment: This will result in an error where this function is used.  'Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled' in other function

Comment: You need to wrap the call in a do/catch block then.

Comment: Oh I see @Gereon So, what should I put inside the catch phrase?

Comment: Whatever code is necessary to handle the thrown error.

Comment: How do I put data from an imported file path into an object?

Comment: That's an entirely new question and should be asked (with a lot more detail of what you're attempting to do) separately.